# How to run javascript code only from single page among all opened pages

Tags: javascript

I've a Javascript file getting loaded in each page request which contains some timer based ajax functions.

What I want is that whenever a new site page is opened it should check if any other existing page is already executing those functions so that it can skip execution them. However if "other" page is closed then it should start executing those.

So the pages look like : example.com/page1.htm, example.com/page2.htm -- all on the same site containing the same Javascript file on separate tabs or windows. Not on Iframes. Even same page can be open in multiple tabs or windows.

What is the way to do it?

I tried Googling this but couldn't find any answers to this.

Comment: Are those "existing" pages in other tabs, or maybe in iframes? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: In other tabs or windows and not in IFrames.

Comment: So you want to poke around the JS running on other pages. Do you think any reasonable browser would let this happen as one of those tabs could be your on-line banking?

Comment: are you talking about multiple instances of the same page or multiple pages? are the pages all on the same domain?

Comment: Yes multiple instances of same page as well as multiple pages

Comment: I don't know why people downvote this perfectly valid question

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - The question wasn't valid when first asked.  I removed my downvote.

Comment: I wrote something like this a few years ago to control volume in YouTube videos. If a new video popped open, no matter which browser or operating system the others were shut off. I wrote it in flash but Im convinced it could be ported to javascript. +1 to you and zero to all the haters :)

Comment: @Shanimal JS is sandboxed from window to window. You would not be able to convert this to JS running on a page. Maybe using chrome or firefox extensions

Comment: How about if you just add a variable flag to localStorage and then each app could poll localStorage for the queue.

Comment: sandboxed from window to window? how do you mean? There are plenty of ways to communicate across windows... i sense a challenge, but it's late.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do cross-tab communication but they are all limited to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

They are:

- [Cookies -- bad idea. Don't do this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie)
- [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)
- [Post Message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) - Limited support in some versions of IE. User beware.

Comment: Cookies have something like a 4K size limit and they are sent to the server on every request.